# Python NameError: name 'ridge_regression_sklearn' is not defined

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, cross-validation, sklearn-pandas

I am working on Cross validation for k-fold using ridge regression. I want to do y_pred using ridge_regression_sklearn and got the error message that 'ridge_regression_sklearn' is not defined.

### Some can please help me how to fix it. I didn't found the right import for it. May be that is the problem???

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-131-34a4b717d52b> in <module>
      1 alphas = np.logspace(-7,7,100)
----> 2 mse_cv = ridgeCV(X_train, y_train, n_folds=10, alphas=alphas)

<ipython-input-130-fea3c1471177> in ridgeCV(X, y, n_folds, alphas)
     33         for k in range(len(alphas)):
---> 35             weights, y_pred = ridge_regression_sklearn(test_X, training_X, training_y, alphas[k])
     36             cv_results_mse[i][k] = mean_squared_error(test_y, y_pred)
     37 

NameError: name 'ridge_regression_sklearn' is not defined
```

I have the following imports for the project i am working

## %matplotlib notebook

%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import loadmat
from scipy import stats
import copy
import pylab
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

Comment: Include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your questions, please.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely something like this would be from ridge_regression_sklearn not being imported. Can you show us how you did import it.

Comment: # %matplotlib notebook
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import loadmat
from scipy import stats
import copy
import pylab
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

Comment: I think i have not added the right import actually i didn't found can you please help me how to find the import for this one

Comment: Do you mean to do linear_model.ridge_regression?

Comment: If that worked please accept my answer. I am trying to get to 50 rep.

Comment: I tried this:    from sklearn.linear_model import ridge_regression  but this is also not working

Comment: I have pip 20.0.2 installed it mean first i need to install pip 30 you mean

Comment: No the pip is fine try to do either pip3 freeze. If that fails do pip freeze. Put the output here.

Comment: I update it to 20.1 which is the latest version i don't know about pip3

Comment: Could you give us the result of pip freeze.